# Find the only periodic solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, physics, periodic-functions

Find the only periodic solution for $y'+y=b(x)$ with $b:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ has a period of $2T$ and is $1$ for $x (0,T)$ and $-1$ for $x (-T,0)$.

The ODE is easy to solve: $y(x) = \exp(-x)\cdot c+1$ and $y(x) = \exp(-x)\cdot c-1$. But how can I find the $c$ such that the solution is periodic with a period of $2T$?

The solution is:

[image: solution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any ODE solution that deserves its name is continuous. So you need to establish continuity at $x=0$ and $y(-T)=y(T)$ to have a periodic solution. For the first you need
$$
1+c_+=-1+c_-\implies c_-=2+c_+
$$
and for the second condition
$$
1+c_+e^{-T}=-1+c_-e^T=-1+(2+c_+)e^T\implies c_+\sinh(T)=1-e^T
$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$
\cases{
y'(t)+y(t)=1\\
-y'(\eta)+y(\eta)=-1, \ \ \ \text{with}\ \ \ \eta = -t
}
$$

and solving we have

$$
y_+(t) = 1+C_+ e^{-t}\\
y_-(\eta) = -1+C_- e^{\eta}
$$

at $t = 0$ for continuity we have

$$
y_+(0)=y_-(0) \Rightarrow 1+C_+ = -1 + C_-
$$

and for periodicity and continuity

$$
y_+(T) = -y_-(-T)\Rightarrow 1+C_+ e^{-T} = -1+C_- e^T
$$

so the constants $C_+,C_-$ are determined from

$$
\cases{
1+C_+ = -1 + C_-\\
1+C_+ e^{-T} = -1+C_- e^T
}
$$